# Julia takes abnormally long to start up, and to run files

Tags: performance, julia

I am running Julia 1.6.3. I have been using Julia for the last 3-4 days. I have a little experience with Python. I am running IJulia on Jupyter notebooks. The first two days things were okay.
Today, it takes a very very long time to simply add packages. My first cell is

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("Plots")
```

This takes about 5 mins to happen. In fact, it is stuck on "Kernel starting, please wait" for a long long time anyway. Further, anytime I want to interrupt the kernel, I just get a message saying "Interrupting Kernel" but nothing really happens. The code continues to run (rather it looks like it's just frozen). I seem to need to restart the kernel and run things all over again and when I try to do that this problem just repeats.

Even simple functions take a very long time. I have already tried reinstalling both Julia and IJulia a few times.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: try from the Julia terminal.. this will help you understand if the problem is related to Jupyter or Julia... also, you may want to try a more developer-friendly editor (Jupyter is very nice to teach) as VSCode or Juno

Comment: Via the Julia terminal things are running, but I still think it's taking longer than it was a few days ago. I am familiar with Spyder. Is it possible to run Julia on Spyder?

Comment: If you interupted the kernel during package installation you have a good chance that Julia package repo got corrupted. In that case you need to delete the `.julia` folder in your home directory and reinstall all packages. Follow the comment by @Antonello and do the package installation from the command line.

Comment: A spider equivalent would be VisualStudio code. BTW these are installation instructions I usually give to my students and could be helpful to you (if StackOverflow allows posting such link)  https://szufel.pl/dsa/JuliaSCF_Installation_instructions_v1.6.3.docx

Comment: This may be a silly question, but you're just adding each package once ever, not once every script run, right? `Pkg.add` is equivalent to `pip install` in the Python world, not `import`.

Comment: @BatWannaBe, thank you!
I did not know that. I was under the impression that it was analogous to `import`

Comment: Yeah, that'll explain the minutes-long startup time, you're (1) downloading everything again, which (2) has to be precompiled again, which (3) has to be compiled again on each run. People complain about Julia's compilation time (3), but it's on the order of seconds, not minutes. `using Plots` is analogous to `import` and will only cost you (3).

Comment: If you are in your development folder, it is a good idea to activate that project (`using Pkg; Pkg.activate(".")` in the REPL, or `] activate .`) this creates a Project.toml file from which you add all your packages for your project. This also means other people know what packages are needed to run your code.